# Efficient way of getting group ID without sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row-number, dense-rank

Imagine I have a denormalized table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    Id           int identity primary key,
    FirstName    nvarchar(100),
    CountryName  nvarchar(100)
)

INSERT INTO Persons
VALUES ('Mark',    'Germany'),
       ('Chris',   'France'),
       ('Grace',   'Italy'),
       ('Antonio', 'Italy'),
       ('Francis', 'France'),
       ('Amanda',  'Italy');
```

I need to construct a query that returns the name of each person, and a unique ID for their country. The IDs do not necessarily have to be contiguous; more importantly, they do **not** have to be in any order. What is the most efficient way of achieving this?

The simplest solution appears to be `DENSE_RANK`:

```
SELECT FirstName, 
       CountryName, 
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CountryName) AS CountryId
FROM Persons

-- FirstName  CountryName  CountryId
-- Chris      France       1
-- Francis    France       1
-- Mark       Germany      2
-- Amanda     Italy        3
-- Grace      Italy        3
-- Antonio    Italy        3
```

However, this incurs a sort on my `CountryName` column, which is a wasteful performance hog. I came up with this alternative, which uses `ROW_NUMBER` with the well-known trick for suppressing its sort:

```
SELECT P.FirstName, 
       P.CountryName,
       C.CountryId
FROM Persons P
    JOIN (
        SELECT CountryName, 
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS CountryId
        FROM Persons
        GROUP BY CountryName
    ) C
    ON C.CountryName = P.CountryName

-- FirstName  CountryName  CountryId
-- Mark       Germany      2
-- Chris      France       1
-- Grace      Italy        3
-- Antonio    Italy        3
-- Francis    France       1
-- Amanda     Italy        3
```

Am I correct in assuming that the second query would perform better in general (not just on my contrived data set)? Are there factors that might make a difference either way (such as an index on `CountryName`)? Is there a more elegant way of expressing it?

Comment: Your first query appears more efficient than your second, for me: http://i.imgur.com/IBalLbl.png

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Thanks, good point.

Answer (score 5):

Why would you think that an aggregation would be cheaper than a window function?  I ask, because I have some experience with both, and don't have a strong opinion on the matter.  If pressed, I would guess the window function is faster, because it does not have to aggregate all the data and then join the result back in.

The two queries will have very different execution paths.  The right way to see which performs better is to try it out.  Run both queries on large enough samples of data in your environment.

By the way, I don't think there is a right answer, because performance depends on several factors:

- Which columns are indexed?
- How large is the data?  Does it fit in memory?
- How many different countries are there?

If you are concerned about performance, and just want a unique number, you could consider using `checksum()` instead.  This does run the risk of collisions.  That risk is very, very small for 200 or so countries.  Plus you can test for it and do something about it if it does occur.  The query would be:

```
SELECT FirstName, CountryName, CheckSum(CountryName) AS CountryId
FROM Persons;
```

Comment: Thanks! I assumed aggregation would be faster since it can be performed using a hash table (taking O(n) time), whilst the window functions require a full sort (taking O(n log n) time). But I agree that the question would depend on the actual data.

Comment: Depending on size of country names, you could also try `convert(int,convert(varbinary,CountryName))`

Answer (score 1):

Your second query would most probably avoid sorting as it would use a hash match aggregate to build the inner query, then use a hash match join to map the ID to the actual records.

This does not sort indeed, but has to scan the original table twice.

> Am I correct in assuming that the second query would perform better in general (not just on my contrived data set)?

Not necessarily. If you created a clustered index on `CountryName`, sorting would be a non-issue and everything would be done in a single pass.

> Is there a more elegant way of expressing it?

A "correct" plan would be doing the hashing and hash lookups in one go.

Each record, as it's read, would have to be matched against the hash table. On a match, the stored ID would be returned; on a miss, the new country would be added into the hash table, assigned with new ID and that newly assigned ID would be returned.

But I can't think of a way to make SQL Server use such a plan in a single query.

**Update:**

If you have lots of records, few countries and, most importantly, a non-clustered index on `CountryName`, you could emulate loose scan to build a list of countries:

```
DECLARE  @country TABLE
         (
         id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
         countryName VARCHAR(MAX)
         )
;

WITH    country AS
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1
                countryName
        FROM    persons
        ORDER BY
                countryName
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  (
                SELECT  countryName
                FROM    (
                        SELECT  countryName,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY countryName) rn
                        FROM    persons
                        WHERE   countryName > country.countryName
                        ) q
                WHERE   rn = 1
                )
        FROM    country
        WHERE   countryName IS NOT NULL
        )
INSERT
INTO    @country (countryName)
SELECT  countryName
FROM    country
WHERE   countryName IS NOT NULL
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0)

SELECT  p.firstName, c.id
FROM    persons p
JOIN    @country c
ON      c.countryName = p.countryName
```

Comment: Yes, I think the last part of your answer is what I was aiming for (although I wasn't versed enough in SQL terminology to express it). I hoped the query optimizer would be smart enough to come up with it for my second query, but Blorgbeard's posted plan confirms it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the proposed solution! I'll give it a test-run tomorrow.

Comment: I think I get the gist of your CTE. However, I can't understand why it would be advantageous over populating `@country` using `distinct`:  `INSERT INTO @country SELECT DISTINCT CountryName FROM Persons`. Would it?

Comment: @Douglas: `SELECT countryname FROM persons` would have to read the whole table. The CTE would have to make as many index seeks as there are countries (plus one final seek). If you have a huge table with few countries (which is you most probably have), the CTE would be more efficient (provided you have an index on `country`, of course).

Comment: If the table has an index on `CountryName`, then `SELECT DISTINCT CountryName FROM Persons` would only incur an index scan. Are you saying that the CTE's sequence of index seeks would be more efficient than a single index scan?

Comment: @Douglas: with lots of records and few countries? Of course.

Answer (score -1):

group by use also    sort operator in background (group is based on 'sort and compare' like Icomparable in C#)

Comment: Not necessarily. `GROUP BY` could be performed by hashing, not sorting.